# AutoPlay OpenLoad, RapidVideo, Streamango

Tags: javascript, html

I don't have any idea how to do autoplay script via iframe but I've found script for tampermonkey. I've tried to do something based on that code but it is not working so if someone can write some example. This is script with autoplay and autonext but I need just for autoplay. I will do autonext from example of autoplay.

```
    function() {


    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var nodes = mutation.addedNodes;
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].nodeName == 'VIDEO') {
                    nodes[i].setAttribute('preload', 'none');
                    nodes[i].removeAttribute('autoplay');
                }
            }
        });
    });

    observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });

})();

$(document).ready(function () {

    var AutPlay = GM_getValue('AutPlay', 1);
    var NxtPlay = GM_getValue('NxtPlay', 1);
    var check1 = '';
    var check2 = '';
    GM_setValue('EpEnded', 0);

    if (AutPlay === 1) {
        check1 = 'checked';
    } else {
        check1 = '';
    }

    if (NxtPlay === 1) {
        check2 = 'checked';
    } else {
        check2 = '';
    }

    var checkbox1 = '<input class="hidden-xs-up" id="AutPlay" type="checkbox" '+check1+' /><label class="AutPlay" for="AutPlay">AutoPlay</label></input>';
    var checkbox2 = '<input class="hidden-xs-up" id="NxtPlay" type="checkbox" '+check2+' /><label class="NxtPlay" for="NxtPlay">NextPlay</label></input>';

    $('#cont').append(checkbox1+checkbox2);

    $('#AutPlay').change(function () {
        if ($('#AutPlay').is(':checked')) {
            AutPlay = 1;
            GM_setValue('AutPlay', 1);
        } else {
            AutPlay = 0;
            GM_setValue('AutPlay', 0);
        }
    });

    $('#NxtPlay').change(function () {
        if ($('#NxtPlay').is(':checked')) {
            NxtPlay = 1;
            GM_setValue('NxtPlay', 1);
        } else {
            NxtPlay = 0;
            GM_setValue('NxtPlay', 0);
        }
    });

    $('#olvideo_html5_api').on('ended', function (e) {
        GM_setValue('EpEnded', 1);
    });

    $('#videojs_html5_api').on('ended', function (e) {
        GM_setValue('EpEnded', 1);
    });

    $('#mgvideo_html5_api').on('ended', function (e) {
        GM_setValue('EpEnded', 1);
    });

    $('#my_video_1_html5_api').on('ended', function (e) {
        GM_setValue('EpEnded', 1);
    });

    setInterval(function(){
        var EpEnded = GM_getValue('EpEnded', 0);
        if( EpEnded === 1 ) {
            Nxt();
            GM_setValue('EpEnded', 0);
        }
    }, 1000); /* interval of video state check. */

    function Nxt() {
        if (NxtPlay === 1) {
            $('.nextbtn').click();
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        if (AutPlay === 1) {
            $('#videooverlay').click();
            $('.vjs-big-play-button').click();
        }
    };

})();
```

Comment: those site require click before playing video and you can't trigger click on iframe so its impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Doe is incorrect. You absolutely can simulate mouse events with JavaScript & jQuery. You can actually do a lot more than that. I wrote an binge (autonext/autoplay) feature for dooplay that works specifically for openload. It does the following

1) cookie creation when activated in player-page. after video player ad, script executes (waits for adcode div to de-spawn)

2) jQuery scrapes time-code from container. used for when show ends and script moves to next episode.

3) simulated mouse events for container to pass ads, maximize and minimize.

If you are interested in this, I could sell you a license.